# Doctrine2 Entity manager find returns empty object

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have entities configured using yaml. 
I can persist and save entities to the database using my entity manager, but when I try to retrieve an entity using the entity manager, I get an empty result.

```
$category = $this->entityManager->find('App\Model\Category', 1);
```

now when I try to display the value of $category:

```
{}
```

but when I try to access an attribute of $category, say

```
$category->getId();
```

I get the right id, and also for the other attributes.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you outputting it to JSON? If so you should read up on using a serializer

Comment: check the id property is defined as ID of the entity class

Comment: *the value of $category* What are you trying to do? Getting the value of an entity? What code do you use?

Comment: @JimL spot on sir, thank you. Can you write you comment as an answer so I can give you credit for your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the name space you are using is wrong?